# Error while installing DRCSIM

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi when I was installing The DRCSIM, i got the next error:

Duplicate sources.list entry http://packages.osrfoundation.org/drc/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages (`/var/lib/apt/lists/packages.osrfoundation.org_drc_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages`)

I TRied UNstalling the DRCSIM and installing AGain; BUt i got the same error Again.

HOw can i solve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1919/error-while-installing-drcsim/) by [Jey_316](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/165/jey_316/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 55 on 2013-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Google says http://askubuntu.com/questions/183007/how-to-fix-duplicate-sources-list-entry-warning.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0